# Ubuntu 18.04 - second screen stay black

Tags: drivers, nvidia, screen, hdmi, monitor

I know there is multiple questions mentioning the same issue but none of them gave me an answer.

I've installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my Asus TUF 765D Laptop. When plugin a secondary screen (that works perfectly on windows), the back light turns on and the screen is detected, but it stays black.

I'm using the nvidia-450-server driver for the graphic card (**EDIT :** also tried nvidia-450 and nvidia-350 with no success). I'm on kernel version 5.4.0-48.

I've tried using the nouveau driver with no results. I've also tried to switch to kernel 5.4.0-47, and saw no improvements. Though I'm suspecting I did it incorrectly as my screen resolution was fixed to a very low value when running this kernel. I've installed it using the following command :

```
sudo apt install linux-headers-5.4.0-47 linux-headers-5.4.0-47-generic linux-image-5.4.0-47-generic
```

I then updated the file `/etc/default/grub` by replacing

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
```

by :

```
GRUB_DEFAULT="Advanced options for Ubuntu>Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-47-generic"
```

Here is the `xrandr` output :

```
eDP connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 382mm x 215mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  40.00  
   1680x1050     60.00  
   1280x1024     60.00  
   1440x900      60.00  
   1280x800      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.00  
   640x480       60.00  
HDMI-1-0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 509mm x 286mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94    50.00  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      59.94    50.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      70.07    60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       59.94    59.93
```

Feel free to ask for any further information,
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `nvidia-driver-450` (without the server suffix).

Also, the GUI for choosing the driver (Software & Updates -> Additional drivers) works very well.
And make sure to reboot.

I have GTX 1050Ti and noveau driver has the same error you described.

Comment: I tried with the normal one. I also tried with version 435 as this is the highest version recommended for my card on the nvidia website. Both attempts were unsuccessful... Also I found the GUI installer not reliable : it was not uninstalling the old version, so when downgrading to 435, the system would still boot with 450.

Comment: @boubside Okay, my next bet would be to update to 20.04, if that's possible. I have the same experience with 18.04 and updating finally fixed this. On 20.04, the solution should work.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm working with ROS and all our production code is on Melodic. We are not ready to move to Neotic just yet. I could try to move to Ubuntu 20 and install ROS Melodic from source but this seems rather painful, so that's my last resort, I'd like to avoid it if I can.

Comment: I feel this is a rather recent problem, as I didn't have this issue on my previous Asus Ubuntu 18.04 laptop with Nvidia graphics. It was working perfectly on driver 440. That's why I'm suspicious of the kernel.